# java runtimeException result

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("a");
    try {
        System.out.print("b");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.print("c");
        throw new RuntimeException("1");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.print("d");
        throw new RuntimeException("2");
    } finally {
        System.out.print("e");
        throw new RuntimeException("3");
    }
}
```

I can not understand why the output is `abce` and RuntimeException("3")

Comment: Hint: tried reading some book or tutorial about how exceptions and try/catch work?

Comment: You should give a tour to Exception tutorial which is the one of the specification of java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: First time I downvote a question. Unlike others I'm all for helping people with simple problems but this is too much. Why couldn't you google "java exception catch finally" and look throw the first 3 or 4 links?

Answer (score 3):

That becomes clear when you *indent* your code as it should be:

```
try {
  System.out.print("b");
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  System.out.print("c");
  throw new RuntimeException("1");
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  System.out.print("d");
  throw new RuntimeException("2");
} finally {
  System.out.print("e");
  throw new RuntimeException("3");
}
```

The point is: there is only **one** try block. And the *first* catch block is taken. That one throws - and *this* exception 1 would be the one you notice in your stacktrace.

But thing is: the *finally* block is throwing "on top" of exception 1. Therefore you see exception 3.

In other words: there is a misconception on your end. You probably assume that exception 1 should be caught by the *second* catch block. And that is wrong. The second catch block **only** covers the first try block. Meaning: an exception from a *catch* block does not result in *another* catch block being taken. The first catch block "fires", and the finally block "fires" - leading to the observed results.

Answer (score 0):

While you can have many `catch()` blocks, a maximum of 1 `catch()` will be executed when an exception is thrown. After that it will execute `finally` block, hence you have the output `abce` and the `RuntimeException` from `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, after IllegalArgumentException thrown in try block, it is caught in corresponding catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { } block. As finally block gets executed regardless of exception, e get printed.

To your question, Since the exception was already caught in catch block it will throw the corresponding exception accordingly and it will get propagated to the caller of that method.